# Show different forms depending of the user choice

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates

I'm trying to create an html page that contains 2 button one click on one of them it add a form to the page, and if I click on the other button it add another form

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function showAppointementForm() {
  document.getElementById("button1").onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("form").innerHTML = `
        <form action="{% url 'create_appointement_non_register_patient' %}" method="POST">
             {{ form.media }} {{ form.as_p }} {% csrf_token %}

            <button type="submit" value="create_appointement_non_register_patient">
                ok
            </button>
        </form>
    `
  }

  document.getElementById("button2").onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("form").innerHTML = `
        <form action="{% url 'create_appointement_register_patient' %}" method="POST">
            <p>
                <label for="patients">select a patient</label>
                <select name="patients" id="patients">
                <option value="">-- select a patient --</option>
                {% for patient in patients %}
                <option value="{{patient}}">{{patient}}</option>
                {%empty%}
                <option value="nothing">nothing</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
            </p> {{ form.media }} {{ form.as_p }} {% csrf_token %}

            <button type="submit" value="create_appointement_register_patient">
                ok
            </button>
        </form>

    `
  }
})
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    
      <button name="type" class="button1" id="button1">register patient</button>
      <button name="type" class="button2" id="button2">non register patient</button>
    
    <div id='form'>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script language="javascripts" type="text/javascripts" src="static/js/onclick.js">
  </script>
</body>
```

is something wrong with my code in js file or is there another way to do it?

This the view that work with the 2 form in the 2 button in the views.py

```py
@login_required
def create_appointement_register_patient(request):
    if request.user.is_doctor() or request.user.is_reception():
        form_app = AppointmentForm_2(request.POST or None)
        user2 = get_user_model()
        patients = user2.objects.filter(type_of_user=TypeOfUser.PATIENT)
        if request.method=='POST':
            form_app = AppointmentForm_2(request.POST or None)
            if form_app.is_valid():
                form_apps = form_app.save(commit=False)
                form_apps.user_ho_add = request.user
                

                start_time = form_apps.start_time 
                future_time = dt.datetime(1970, 1, 1, start_time.hour, start_time.minute, start_time.second, start_time.microsecond) + timedelta(minutes=30)
                form_apps.end_time = dt.time(future_time.hour, future_time.minute, future_time.second, future_time.microsecond)
                form_apps.patient = request.POST['patients']
                if Appointment.objects.filter(patient=request.POST['patients']).exists():
                    form_apps.save()
                    messages.success(request, 'appointment added')
                else:
                    raise ValidationError('patient does not Exist')
            else:
                messages.error(request, 'Error')

            return render(request,'appointement/add_appointement2.html',{'form':form_app, 'patients':patients}) 
        else:
            return render(request,'appointement/add_appointement2.html',{'form':form_app, 'patients':patients})
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("create_appointement"))


@login_required
def create_appointement_non_register_patient(request):
    if request.user.is_doctor() or request.user.is_reception():
        form_app = AppointmentForm_3(request.POST or None)
        user2 = get_user_model()
        patients = user2.objects.filter(type_of_user=TypeOfUser.PATIENT)
        if request.method=='POST':
            form_app = AppointmentForm_3(request.POST or None)
            if form_app.is_valid():
                form_apps = form_app.save(commit=False)
                form_apps.user_ho_add = request.user
                

                start_time = form_apps.start_time 
                future_time = dt.datetime(1970, 1, 1, start_time.hour, start_time.minute, start_time.second, start_time.microsecond) + timedelta(minutes=30)
                form_apps.end_time = dt.time(future_time.hour, future_time.minute, future_time.second, future_time.microsecond)
                form_apps.save()
                messages.success(request, 'appointment added')
            else:
                messages.error(request, 'Error')

            return render(request,'appointement/add_appointement3.html',{'form':form_app, 'patients':patients}) 
        else:
            return render(request,'appointement/add_appointement3.html',{'form':form_app, 'patients':patients})
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("create_appointement"))
```

Answer (score 1):

it is possible to use `render` or `render_to_string` in django-side of the code.
as you showing the base for first time, but at this time you're using ajax so take an advantage of ajax, the `success` method. e.g:

```js
    $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'GET',

            success: function (res) {
                $('#gmodalContent').html(res);
            },

            error: function (er) {
                console.log(er);
            },
        });
```

I used `html()` but there are also `append()`, `prepend()` and other methods available out there in js.

- the `res` is referring to the response from django side which is provided using `render` or `render_to_string`.

Comment: my problem is in the javascripts code that did not work not in the django side of the code, is the js code good dose it work ???

Comment: it seems the html code is not good. because you already put the buttons inside a form. take them out and drop that initial form. also the buttons are typed `submit` which by default tells the browser when each of them clicked submit the form and after that you're js code won't work at all.

Comment: I change that in my VS code, but it did not work, but when I edit the code in here (in the question) it works when I click on the button it show me the form, I added the function in Django if you can see where the error is that will be great

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are passing the javascript source through the template processor, and I don't see any indication you do, you are just simply adding verbatim the code to the page. Instead put all the forms in the template hidden with `display:none` and make the button unhide them.

The best implementation is to create a route for each form, so that the user is presented with the form of their selection.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of this method but I want to make the html page show nothing unless I click the button that way id did not interfere with the Django side, is there a way to make it possible by using the innerhtml method in js

Comment: @houhou you are already modifying served files, why not modify the application to do what you want. Modify the template and include both forms if you don't want a roundtrip when the user press the button. In fact, you have already two functions to handle each route. Create two routes on the urls, each one handled by each function and with their own template. Doing it any other way, is making it more complicated than in needs to.

Comment: this is a cs 50 final project i need to do it with javascripts and django, i want to make it work like this and after that i will add a popup small html that contait the form with javascripts, but know like this ( the simpleset way it did not work )

Comment: @houhou unless that's part of the assignment (in which case, I believe you are wasting your time), you are the one that decide how to achieve it. It's less painful to do it how I'm suggesting.